# How to close a Data Reader

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I continue to receive the error that "`There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.`" when I execute following in ASP.NET MVC 4.5

```
        foreach (var store in db.Stores)
        {
            var productsInStore = store.Products.ToList();
        }
```

In my solution there a class called Store and in this particular example, I am trying to convert the Products inside each store into a new variable.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force EF to load all entities immediately. To do so call ToList():

```
    foreach (var store in db.Stores.ToList())
    {
        var productsInStore = store.Products.ToList();
    }
```